# Packing rectangles inside a rectangle

Tags: c#, algorithm, packing

I was trying to find some algorithm that would pack a bunch of different rectangles inside a rectangle with fixed width and unlimited length. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything relevant.

I thought of implementing this algorithm inside a C# program, but any other programming language (or even pseudo-code) is fine. While doing a research, I stumbled upon some Stack Overflow and Wikipedia articles, but none of them were useful.

Time and memory consumption aren't the priority here, I just need the algorithm to work. Also, there has to be spacing between rectangles which user can modify by his needs, so RectpackSharp
or any similar library isn't really useful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you take care of the spacing by extending all the rectangles by half of the required spacing? Are the sizes and coordinates of the rectangles integers or "real numbers" (as far as computers can approximate them)?

Comment: Sizes of rectangles are integers, entered by user. Extending rectangles is fine, as the visual representation isn't a priority. Also, you can rotate the rectangles in order to take less space.

Comment: Rotate 90 degrees, or also some less convenient angles?

Comment: 90 degrees only